# Problema con char en un bucle while en c++

Tags: c++, funciones, while, char

Hola buen dia al que lea esto, escribo esto porque tengo un problema en una funcion de mi programa. El problema en cuestion es que al momento de capturar el sexo en con un `char` lo captura pero al ingresa el `while` entra el bucle y no sale del el sin importa que haya ingresado bien los datos a continuacion la parte del problema:

```
cout<<"\nItroduzca el sexo de la persona (masculino=m),(femenino=f): "; cin>>persona1[posicion].sexo;


    while((persona1[posicion].sexo!='m')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='M')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='f')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='F'))
    {
        cout<<"\nIngrese m o f : ";
        cout<<"\nm=Masculino\nf=femenino";
        cout<<"\nIngrese el sexo nuevamente: ";
        cin>>persona1[posicion].sexo;

    }
```

Todo la funcion:

```
void rellenar()
{

        short int actividad,again;

    do{
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el nombre de la persona 1: "; cin.getline(persona1[posicion].nombre,90,'\n');

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca la edad de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1[posicion].edad;
    while((persona1[posicion].edad<1)||(persona1[posicion].edad>127))
    {
        cout<<"\nLa edad tiene que ser mayor a 0 y menor a 127 (1-127): ";
        cout<<"\nIngrese la edad nuevamente: ";
        cin>>persona1[posicion].edad;
    }

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el peso en kg de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1[posicion].peso;
    while((persona1[posicion].peso<20)||(persona1[posicion].peso>199))
    {
        cout<<"\nEl peso tiene que ser mayor a 20kgs y menor a 199kgs (20-199): ";
        cout<<"\nIngrese el peso nuevamente: ";
        cin>>persona1[posicion].peso;
    }

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca la altura en mts de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1[posicion].altura;
    while((persona1[posicion].altura<1)||(persona1[posicion].altura>2.70))
    {
        cout<<"\nEl peso tiene que ser mayor a 1 mts y menor a 2.70 mts(20-199): ";
        cout<<"\nIngrese la altura nuevamente: ";
        cin>>persona1[posicion].altura;
    }

    cout<<"\nItroduzca el sexo de la persona (masculino=m),(femenino=f): "; cin>>persona1[posicion].sexo;


    while((persona1[posicion].sexo!='m')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='M')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='f')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='F'))
    {
        cout<<"\nIngrese m o f : ";
        cout<<"\nm=Masculino\nf=femenino";
        cout<<"\nIngrese el sexo nuevamente: ";
        cin>>persona1[posicion].sexo;

    }

cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout<<"\n\nPara finalizar ingrese la opcion\n\nIndique el tipo de actividad fisica de la persona: \n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\n6-Mostrar metabolismo basal bruto\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  ";
    cin>>actividad;
    while((actividad<1)||(actividad>6))
    {
        cout<<"\t\nIngrese el numero de la opcion (1-5): ";
            cout<<"\n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\n6-Mostrar metabolismo basal bruto\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  ";

        cin>>actividad;
    }

    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n\tLos datos estan correctos: ";
    cout<<"\n\tPresione 1 para capturar datos otra vez\n\tPresione 2 para seguir  ";
    cout<<"\n\tIngrese la opcion: ";
    cin>>again;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}while(again==1);

    metabolismo1(persona1[posicion].peso,persona1[posicion].altura,persona1[posicion].edad,actividad);
    posicion++;


}
```

Comment: Veo que no incrementas la variable "posición", así que siempre mirará la misma posición.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de tu código esta en la condición del **while**.
Tu condición dice:

```
while((persona1[posicion].sexo!='m')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='M')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='f')||(persona1[posicion].sexo!='F'))
```

Que en terminos logicos diría:

```
Mientras( sexo != 'm' || sexo != 'M' || sexo != 'f' || sexo != 'F' )
{
   pide otra vez el sexo.
}
```

Ahora bien. El **||** es un **or** y será verdadero cuando se cumpla alguna de las 4 condiciones que has puesto.

Si escribo **M**  entonces  **sexo!='m'** será verdadera y se volverá ejecutar.

Tu condición debería decir:

```
Mientras( sexo != 'm' && sexo != 'M' && sexo != 'f' && sexo != 'F' )
```

Esto porque tu deseas que se ejecute el código mientras el sexo que introduzcan sea diferente de m y de M y de f y de F.

Por favor coméntame si esto te ha funcionado.